# Why do many methods in Android framework end with 'locked'

Tags: android

When I read android source code, I notice that lots of methods end with **locked**. e.g. in `ActivityStackSupervisor`

[image]

I'm just curious does it mean these methods are *thread safe*? Or is it a naming convention?